# Service Bind SecurityException

Tags: android

I have an application A which has an Activity and a Service.

I have an another application B which bind to service and access the public method from the Service.
When I try to bindService from Application B it gives the following error.

As this is a security exception, does it something related to Signing of application?

Service:

```
    public class CalculatorService extends Service {

    public CalculatorService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    ICalculatorService.Stub mBinder = new ICalculatorService.Stub()

    {

        @Override
        public int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
            return a+b;
        }

        @Override
        public void basicTypes(int anInt, long aLong, boolean aBoolean, float aFloat, double aDouble, String aString) throws RemoteException {

        }
    };
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name=".Services.CalculatorService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.xxx.aidltest.Services.ICalculatorService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Call to Service from another App:

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ConnectAidlService();
        }

        ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
                calcInterface = ICalculatorService.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
                try {
                    Log.d("Amol","Addition="+calcInterface.add(6,7));
                } catch(RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {

            }
        };

        public void ConnectAidlService(){
            Intent i = new Intent(ICalculatorService.class.getName());
            i.setClassName("com.example.xxx.aidltest","com.example.xxx.aidltest.Services.CalculatorService");
            getApplicationContext().bindService(i,mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
```

Error:

```
com.example.XXX.clientserviceapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.xxxclientserviceapp, PID: 22447
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xxx.clientserviceapp/com.example.xxx.clientserviceapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.example.xxx.clientserviceapp.ICalculatorService cmp=com.example.xxx.aidltest/.Services.CalculatorService }
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.example.xxx.clientserviceapp.ICalculatorService cmp=com.example.xxx.aidltest/.Services.CalculatorService }
                                                                                         at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1468)
                                                                                         at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1422)
                                                                                         at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:636)
                                                                                         at com.example.xxx.clientserviceapp.MainActivity.ConnectAidlService(MainActivity.java:45)
                                                                                         at com.example.xxx.clientserviceapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6723)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
```

Comment: please no images of code/errors

Comment: Starting on Android 5.0, you are not allowed to bind to a service using an implicit `Intent` (one that does not specify the actual service itself). You appear to be doing that via `setClassName()`, but it is somewhat difficult to tell, since you posted images, not text.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry about that. I have corrected the code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: What you have seems like it should be fine. I cannot explain the stack trace from your original screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in my code.
The AIDL file I have copied to the client app has incorrect package name.

Realize the error after reading the following from developer site:

> Call the methods that you defined on your interface. You should always
>   trap DeadObjectException exceptions, which are thrown when the
>   connection has broken. You should also trap SecurityException
>   exceptions, which are thrown when the two processes involved in the
>   IPC method call have conflicting AIDL definitions.